# How can I find and calculate the repeats?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code that lets you input five classes with five students in them, then the output will tell you who is repeated and how many times.

Ex.

Input:

Johnny, Lily, Johnny, Random, Miii

Wii, Random, Johnny, Lily, Umm

Jay, Johnny, Random, Wii, Err

Johnny, Johnny, Johnny, Johnny, Johnny

???, Hi, Bye, Example, Johnny

Somthing, Exampletwo, Examplethree, Ex, Exx

**Output:**

Johnny:10

Lily: 2

Random: 3

Wii: 2

*Thanks :)*

```
print('Each class has five students.')
a=input('Enter the first class students. ')
b=input('Enter the second class students. ')
c=input('Enter the third class students. ')
d=input('Enter the fourth class students. ')
e=input('Enter the fith class students. ')
```

Comment: Can you give us the actual piece of code where you are defining each list?

Comment: I think I did it.

Comment: @Phantom I believe they were asking for an actual Python list, which is much more convenient for us to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you use [Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(a + b + c + d + e) # Add all lists together, and then count them
```

**NOTE:** You have to convert the inputs into lists first. Here is how you can do that (based on your input - you can change the `", "` into whatever you want):

```
print('Each class has five students.')
a=input('Enter the first class students. ').split(", ")
b=input('Enter the second class students. ').split(", ")
c=input('Enter the third class students. ').split(", ")
d=input('Enter the fourth class students. ').split(", ")
e=input('Enter the fith class students. ').split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution without using Counter

```
count = dict()

#repeat for 5 classes
for i in range(0, 5):
    students = input().split(", ")

    #add student to count
    for s in students:
        if s in count:
            count[s] += 1
        else:
            count[s] = 1

for student, occurrences in count.items():

    #print if more than one occurence
    if occurrences >= 2:
        print(student + ":" + str(occurrences))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a function to handle this

```
 # Data
class_1 = ['Johnny', 'Lily', 'Johnny', 'Random', 'Miii']
class_2 = ['Wii', 'Random', 'Johnny', 'Lily', 'Umm']
class_3 = ['Jay', 'Johnny', 'Random', 'Wii', 'Err']
class_4 = ['Johnny', 'Johnny', 'Johnny', 'Johnny', 'Johnny']
class_5 = ['???', 'Hi', 'Bye', 'Example', 'Johnny']
```

Function (it can handle multiple lists)

```
from collections import Counter

def count_names(*args, **kwargs):
    mylist = [name for name_list in args for name in name_list]
    return Counter(mylist)
```

Result:

```
count_names(class_1, class_2, class_3, class_4, class_5)

Counter({'Johnny': 10,
         'Lily': 2,
         'Random': 3,
         'Miii': 1,
         'Wii': 2,
         'Umm': 1,
         'Jay': 1,
         'Err': 1,
         '???': 1,
         'Hi': 1,
         'Bye': 1,
         'Example': 1})
```